# В чому полягає відмінність слова "мимохіть" від "мимохідь"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, граматика, правопис

Є декілька посилань, які пояснюють, в яких випадках слід вживати *"мимохідь"*, а в яких — *"мимохіть"*:

- [Укр-мова](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/mimohit-i-mimohid)
- [Slovopedia](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53404/31384.html)
- [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%96-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8C/)
- [Київська міська бібліотека](http://lib.misto.kiev.ua/UKR/VPRAVA/MOVA/SKLADNE_SLOVOVJIVANNA/mimohid_mimohit.dhtml)

Comment: І що саме Вас не влаштовує у поданих вище джерелах?

Comment: Приєднуюся до попереднього коментаря: авторка запитання досить ретельно дослідила проблему, але зовсім незрозуміло, у чому са́ме полягає запитання.

Comment: Можливо, це була спроба не запитати, а надати інформацію? Stack Exchange не забороняє це, а навіть, навпаки, заохочує. Але: (1) запитання в такому випадку має бути оформлене, як запитання; (2) під час створення запитання треба натиснути на галочку «Answer your own question» і ввести відповідь **в окремому полі**, що з'явиться ничже; (3) відповідь має містити, власне, відповідь (інформацію в тексті), а не бути набором посилань.